# How to calculate SVG Linear Gradient

Tags: d3.js, svg, linear-gradients

If I have an upward sloping straight line is it possible to set the gradient fill such that it is red when the curved line is below the straight line and blue when above. Below are the two line functions and the d3 area function generator and their associated arrays.

```
//global Variables:

var trendGrowthX =[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var trendGrowthY = [2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7];
var actualX = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var actualY = [2,4.3,5.5,3.5,2,3,5.5,7.5,6.5,5.5,5];


//D3 path generator functions:

 function addTrend(){
 var trendLine = d3.line()
 .x(function(d,i,a){return xScale(trendGrowthX[i]);})
 .y(function(d,i,a){return xScale(trendGrowthY[i]);})
}

function addActual(){
 var actualIncome = d3.line()
 .x(function(d,i,a){return xScale(actualX[i])})
 .y(function(d,i,a){return yScale(actualY[i])})
 .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha(0.5))

 g.append("path").attr("d",actualIncome(actualX))
 .style("stroke","green")
 .style("stroke-width",3)

}

function addArea(){
 var area = d3.area()
 .attr("x1",function(d,i,a){return xScale(actualX[i]); })
 .attr("y1",function(d,i,a){return xScale(actualY[i]); })
 .attr("y0",function(d,i,a){return xScale(trendGrwothY[i]); })
 .attr("x0",function(d,i,a){return xScale(trendGrowthX[i]); })

 g.append("path")
 .attr("d",function(d,i,a){ area(actualX)})
 .style("fill","url(#area-gradient)")
 .attr("pointer-events","none")
}
```

[image: current output]

Answer (score 0):

SVG has a transformGradient property to allow you to manipulate the linear gradient using standard transform instructions, solution is below:

```
var gradient = d3.select("#area- gradient").attr("gradientTransform",`rotate(-18),${xScale(trendGrowthX[5]),${yScale(trendGrowthY[5])})`);
```